# I want to turn on and turn off camera on the same screen in flutter app during particular time intervals

Tags: flutter, camera

Thanks in Advance

Currently my app uses camera to take video input and process each frames . The app also works in background for hours. So to avoid heating issues I need to turn the camera off and on it later.

The camera is turned off when I use

`_camera.dispose()`

but its not turned on after disposing when I use

`_camera.initialize()`

```
    CameraDescription description = await getCamera(_direction);
    ImageRotation rotation = rotationIntToImageRotation(
      description.sensorOrientation,
    );
       _camera =CameraController(description, ResolutionPreset.low, enableAudio: false);
    await _camera.initialize();
  _camera.startImageStream((CameraImage image) { 
         _baseStopwatch.start();
          if (_baseStopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds > 5) {
              _camera.stopImageStream(); }
          if (_baseStopwatch.elapsed.inSeconds > 10){
             // need to restart the camera streaming!!
          }}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga Thank you for the reply. Currently I am trying to start and stop the imagestream